# Windows non-Blue Screens of Death... Green and Orange?

Tags: windows, windows-10, bsod, crash

#### Rainbow Screens of Death (Gotta Catch 'Em All!)

The Blue Screen of Death (BSOD) is well-known, even if not well-loved:

[image: Blue SoD]

I've also observed the following Green and Orange Screens of Death:

[image: Green SoD]

[image: Orange SoD]

Is there some meaning to the colours of the background?

What other colours are available?  Gotta Catch 'Em All!!!

Comment: It’s probably the active system theme color.

Comment: @DanielB Nope, Insider preview and GPU issues give Green and Orange respectively... I wonder how many more there are?

Answer (score 2):

#### Green

[This article](https://www.theverge.com/2016/12/29/14111584/microsoft-windows-10-green-screen-of-death) says that the GSOD is only for Insider Preview releases.

This is not true, as the photo above was from Win10 LTSC 2019.

#### Orange

[GPU issues](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-10-orange-screen-of-death) are supposedly the culprit when a OSOD is observed.

The `UNEXPECTED_STORE_EXCEPTION` in the photo doesn't seem very GPU related.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, BSODs happen when the computer is overloaded and runs out of space in the pagefile and swapfile or there is too little RAM for any system functions and they are killed naturally by the OS itself. GSODs happen when those processes are killed artificially, either by the person running the computer or by another rogue process. And OSODs only happen when there are GPU or memory problems. I say memory problems because of the `UNEXPECTED_STORE_EXCEPTION` error it threw.

Answer (score 0):

Many BSODs are listed in the article
[Purple, Brown, Yellow, Orange, Red, Green Screen of Death explained](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/purple-brown-yellow-red-green-screen-of-death).

**Purple Screen of Death**

Mainly seen when the VMkernel of an ESX/ESXi host experiences a critical error,
becomes inoperative and terminates any virtual machines that are running.
Requires reboot using the power button.

**Brown Screen of Death**

Mostly associated with game-plays, linked mainly to graphics.
Usually arrives when a PC game forces CPU and memory to run at speeds higher than
their official speed grade (over-clocking).

**Yellow Screen of Death**

Happened usually with Firefox accompanied by a weird buzzing sound, after an XML.
Probably does not exist any more.

**Red Screen of Death**

Mostly indicates issues related to the graphics driver and the corresponding
applications, caused usually by installing wrong drivers or by software conflicts
on boot.

**Orange Screen of Death**

Usually indicates fatal hardware errors and has many causes such as
watching a video, when booting into Windows, waking up from Sleep, BitLocker,
or when adding a second monitor

**Green Screen of Death**

Intended for Windows Insiders testing for upcoming Windows 10 test builds,
to make it easier for Microsoft support staff to differentiate between errors
in test builds and in production.

As Microsoft staff are not infallible, sometimes colored BSODs happen not
according to the above purpose.

Comment: I doubt the veracity of the source article you paraphrase. A Firefox XML parse error causing a Yellow SoD? The article lists no sources :(

Comment: The yellow BSOD probably existed with an older Windows and Mozilla versions. I remarked above that it "Probably does not exist any more". But software errors can really cause weird BSODs - we get enough of them on this site.